# Apache Mod rewrite not work for me When use (-) in url?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apache Mod rewrite not work for me When use (-) in url?

I tried to access to page

```
www.example.com/products/ipod/white-ipod-8gb/12345678
```

it's not work, How can i edit `.htaccess` file ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^-]*)/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ /products.php?produucts_name=$1&products_des=$2&products_id=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]    
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
Options -indexes
```

Comment: The `-` character has special meaning in regex patterns. You need to escape it with backslash like so `\-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your use of `[^-]` in your regex. Use this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
Options -indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?produucts_name=$1&products_des=$2&products_id=$3 [L]
```